# speeding up mysql queries / mysql views in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, query-optimization, sql-view

I use the following code to select popular news entries (by date) from the database:

```
popular = Entry.objects.filter(type='A', is_public=True).extra(select = {'dpub': 'date(dt_published)'}).order_by('-dpub', '-views', '-dt_written', 'headline')[0:5]
```

To compare the execution speeds of a normal query and this one I ran the following mysql queries:

```
SELECT *, date(dt_published) as dpub FROM `news_entry` order by dpub DESC LIMIT 500

# Showing rows 0 - 29 (500 total, Query took 0.1386 sec)
```

-

```
SELECT * , DATE( dt_published ) AS dpub FROM  `news_entry` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500

# Showing rows 0 - 29 (500 total, Query took 0.0021 sec) [id: 58079 - 57580]
```

As you can see the normal query is much faster. Is there a way to  speed this up?

Is it possible to use mysql views with django?

I realize I could just split the datetime field into two fields (date and time), but I'm curious.

---

#### Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_entry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `headline` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `subheadline` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_public` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `dt_written` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_published` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_alt` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `email_alt` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, date(dt_published) as dpub FROM `news_entry` order by dpub DESC LIMIT 500
```

This query orders on `dpub`, while this one:

```
SELECT * , DATE( dt_published ) AS dpub FROM  `news_entry` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
```

orders on `id`.

Since `id` is most probably a `PRIMARY KEY` for your table, and each `PRIMARY KEY` has an implicit index backing it, `ORDER BY` does not need to sort.

`dpub` is a computed field and `MySQL` does not support indexes on computed fields. However, `ORDER BY dt_published` is an `ORDER BY dpub` as well.

You need to change your query to this:

```
SELECT *, date(dt_published) as dpub FROM `news_entry` order by date_published DESC LIMIT 500
```

and create an index on `news_entry (dt_published)`.

**Update:**

Since `DATE` is a monotonic function, you may employ this trick:

```
SELECT  *, DATE(dt_published) AS dpub
FROM    news_entry
WHERE   dt_published >=
        (
        SELECT  md
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DATE(dt_published) AS md
                FROM    news_entry
                ORDER BY
                        dt_published DESC
                LIMIT 499, 1
                ) q
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATE(MIN(dt_published))
        FROM    news_entry
        LIMIT 1
        )
ORDER BY
        dpub DESC, views DESC, dt_written DESC, headline
LIMIT 500
```

This query does the following:

- Selects the `500th` record in `dt_published DESC` order, or the first record posted should there be less than `500` records in the table.
- Fetches all records posted later than the **date** of the last record selected. Since `DATE(x)` is always less or equal to `x`, there can be more than `500` records, but still 
  much less than the whole table.
- Orders and limits these records as appropriate.

You may find this article interesting, since it covers a similar problem:

- [**Things SQL needs: sargability of monotonic functions**](http://explainextended.com/2010/02/19/things-sql-needs-sargability-of-monotonic-functions/)

Comment: Thank you for the datailed answer. However this is not the answer to my question. I know I can't create an index on a computed field. But I'm not very familiar with views so I thought they might help me if I knew more about them. It is not possible to order by dt_published since I also want to order by views/clicks. order_by('-dpub', '-views', '-dt_written', 'headline')

Comment: @Arnar: `MySQL` cannot push predicates into the views: the view will be executed and buffered first, then all other predicates applied. If you need to order by additional fields, you can implement a certain trick (I'll put it to the post now).

Answer (score 0):

May need an index on `dt_published`. Could you post the query plans for the two queries?

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that dpub is a computed field and it can't be an index.

Comment: No, not on dpub... create index inx_news_entry_dt on news_entry (dt_published); It may help.

Comment: added table structure to question, and yes, I did that.